# php & maths - rounding?

Tags: php

Basically, I have a number:

```
<?
$rating = 72.7777777778;
?>
```

I basically want to do some maths to create this number as 80.

If the number was `62.7777777778`, the number would be 60.

I want the numbers rounded like so:

```
20, 40, 60, 80, 100
```

So say I have three numbers:

```
36.999, 47, 91
```

I would get:

```
40, 40, 100
```

How do I go about doing this? I've tried with round, ceil & floor but I haven't got anywhere.

Would it just be easier doing something like so?

```
if ($rating < 30){
    $rating = 20;
}elseif (($rating > 30) && ($rating < 50)){
    $rating = 40;
}elseif (($rating > 50) && ($rating < 70)){
    $rating = 60;
}elseif (($rating > 70) && ($rating < 90)){
    $rating = 80;
}else{
    $rating = 100;
}
```

etc...

Comment: you can check the $rating % 20 is bigger or smaller from 10, if bigger round to up if smaller round it down

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$rounded = round(62.222 / 20) * 20;
```

Comment: @Laurent, if you use 91.0 it does equal 100 at the end.

Comment: Or more simply, replace 62.222 with $rating

Comment: @Laurent: I **strongly recommend** you to check your thoughts before blaming: `var_dump(round(91 / 20) * 20 == 100);` http://ideone.com/h6uDR And after you agreed you were wrong can you take your downvote back please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Laurent missed `round` and took it as `floor`, though harsh words are never needed.

Comment: After seeing the comments on this, I had to run this myself just to assure myself that I hadn't had a stroke. This *does* work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $rating = round($rating/20.0)*20
```

Comment: I'm only guessing because someone else posted this before, or someone was downvoting all other answers.

Comment: @DMan as this is the same as zerkms' answer, I'd say it's fairly apparent who the downvoter is. Why they haven't removed said downvotes is a mystery

Comment: @Phil - While I make no assumptions, unfortunately 'tactical downvoting' is common.

Comment: @DMan Oh, not accusing zerkms here. The comments reveal a more likely culprit

Comment: Hehe, to stop talking about me like a bad guy I'll upvote this answer :-)

Comment: @Phil - Don't know who you are pointing to then ;) I'll +1 as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want everything consistently rounded to the nearest `<value>`, then divide by `<value>`, round, and multiply by `<value>`.

```
 // replace this with 20 to get 20,40,60,80...
 // or with 7 to get 7, 14, 21, 28, 35...
 // or with...........
 $roundedBy = 10;
 $toRound = 75;
 echo 
    // 7.5 -> 8
    round( $toRound / $roundedBy )
    // 8 * 10 = 80;
    * roundedBy;
```

If you want to round up, replace `round` with `ceil`. If you want to round down replace `round` with `floor`.

Unfortunately, your numbers seem to be inconsistent with rounding: `36.999, 47` will round to 40 and 50 respectively.

As to your if... else statements, you can shorten them:

```
if ($rating < 30){
    $rating = 20;
}elseif ($rating < 50){ // will always already be >= 30
    $rating = 40;
}elseif ($rating < 70){ // will always already be >= 70
    $rating = 60;
}elseif ($rating < 90){ // will always already be >= 70
    $rating = 80;
}else{ // will always already be >= 90
    $rating = 100;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$roundedBy = 20;`? We're using increments of 20, not 10.

Comment: He's using 20 as the `$roundedBy` figure so 47 does round to 40